# why can awk function called without parentheses

Tags: awk

Is `print` a function or statement.

Why parentheses are not required?

I couldn't find any information about this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` is a statement that doesn't require (but optionally accepts) parentheses.

> The entire list of items may
>   optionally be enclosed in parentheses.
>   The parentheses are necessary if any
>   of the item expressions uses the `>'
>   relational operator; otherwise it
>   could be confused with a redirection

(see [The print Statement](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/Misc/Unix-info/awk/gawk_7.html#SEC56))

Some people always use the parentheses, because e.g. they prefer the function syntax and it has no negative side effects.

Comment: What makes a phrase a statement is either (1) its ability to occur in certain syntactic contexts, for instance as a complete line of the awk script, or (2) its not returning a value. By either understanding, `print` is a statement. Both understandings are problematic though. The first because on some (but not all) awk implementations, any expression can occur in a statement context, so on this understanding all expressions would be statements. The second because assignments and user-defined function calls return values but the first is indisputably and the second is disputably a statement.

Comment: There are also functions that don't require parentheses: `getline` is one example, and on some implementations of awk, you can use `length` without parentheses as a shorthand for `length($0)`.

Comment: @dubiousjim: Please feel free to edit the answer as necessary on the finer points I may have left out or not understood.

Comment: I didn't mean to criticize your answer, but just to think out loud about the (not-immediately obvious) difficulties giving a principled account of why, for example, print is counted a statement in awk, but getline is counted a function.

Comment: There is a huge difference between statements and expressions (function calls are expressions).  Expressions return something.  For example, take the sprintf() FUNCTION.  It is similar to printf, except that it RETURNS a string.  print and printf don't return anything (it doesn't make much sense for them to return a value).  That means that you can't do `length(print $1)`, that doesn't make sense.  But you can do `length(sprintf("%s", $1))`.